# Why does the same statement print two different values?

Tags: python

As I'm tying to understand the python self concept, I came across this example that I thought was helpful. But there is one part that confuses me. Why does `print a.i`  output two different values? In the first case the output is `5` which makes sense to me. But then a few lines later the same `print a.i` statement outputs `123`.

```
def say_hi():
    return 'hi!'

i = 789

class MyClass(object):

    i = 5

    def prepare(self):
        i = 10
        self.i = 123
        print i

    def say_hi(self):
        return 'Hi there!'

    def say_something(self):
        print say_hi()

    def say_something_else(self):
        print self.say_hi()
```

Output

```
>>> print say_hi()
hi!
>>> print i
789
>>> a = MyClass()
>>> a.say_something()
hi!
>>> a.say_something_else()
Hi there!
>>> print a.i
5
>>> a.prepare()
10
>>> print i
789
>>> print a.i
123
```

Comment: you call `a.prepare()`, in which you have `self.i = 123`

Answer (score 5):

You are using global, local and instance attributes with the same name:

```
def say_hi():        # This is the global function 'say_hi'
    return 'hi!'    

i = 789              # This is the global 'i'

class MyClass(object):

    i = 5  # This is a class attribute 'i'

    def prepare(self):
        i = 10           # Here, you are creating a new 'i' (local to this function)
        self.i = 123     # Here, you are changing the instance attribute 'i'
        print i          # Here, you are printing the new'ed 'i' (now with value 10)

    def say_hi(self):         # This is the object method 'say_hi' function
        return 'Hi there!'

    def say_something(self):
        print say_hi()         # Here, you are calling the global 'say_hi' function

    def say_something_else(self):
        print self.say_hi()    # Here, you are calling the object method 'say_hi' function
```

So the ouput is correct:

```
>>> print say_hi()          # global
hi!
>>> print i                 # global
789
>>> a = MyClass()
>>> a.say_something()       # say_something calls the global version
hi!
>>> a.say_something_else()  # say_something_else calls the object version
Hi there!
>>> print a.i               # class attribute 'i'
5
>>> a.prepare()             # prints the local 'i' and change the class attribute 'i'
10
>>> print i                 # global 'i' is not changed at all
789
>>> print a.i               # class attribute 'i' changed to 123 by a.prepare()
123
```

Comment: I would use the term instance attribute (rather than object property - a proerty is a very specific thing in python), but this is the correct answer in terms of scope and instance attributes.

Comment: It's even more confusing - the first `a.i` isn't an instance attribute but a class attribute. `prepare` masks it by creating the instance attribute.

Comment: `class attribute 'i' changed to 123 by a.prepare()`: no. `a.prepare()` changes the class attribute to `10`, and creates the instance attribute `self.i = 123`

Comment: @njzk2: The `i` which is set to 10 is a local variable in `prepare`. `prepare` doesn't access the class attribute. Unlike C++, Python's methods do not inherit the namespace of their class; that is accessed via `self`.

Comment: @YannVernier: ok, my bad, you indeed need to access to `MyClass.i` to change the class attribute

Answer (score 4):

Before the following statement in `prepare` method:

```
self.i = 123
```

`self.i` references a class attribute `MyClass.i` (because the instance attribute is not set)

Once the `self.i = ..` statement is executed, `self.i` reference a new value `123`. (This does not affect the class attribute `MyClass.i`, making a new instance attribute)

Comment: self.i refers to an instance Attribute - MyClass.i refers to a class attribute - two very different things.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66, `self.i` refers class attribute when there's no instance attribute named `i`.

Comment: ok - I accept that you are correct.... I hope no-one ever writes production code which uses that....

Comment: @TonySuffolk66, It's used commonly, even in standard library. For example,  https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/90b07d422bd9/Lib/ftplib.py#l156  https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/90b07d422bd9/Lib/ftplib.py#l156

Comment: @TonySuffolk66, FYI, Search for `class attributes` in the [Data models - Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types). (2nd occurrence)

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the class variable i to 123 in the `prepare()` function:

```
    self.i = 123
```

After which you are calling the class variable by doing `print a.i` which will print 123 as a result.

Comment: But I thought self is pointing to the instance; not the class ? In other words self.i is changing the value in the instance a but not the class variable.

Comment: self.i (or a.i) does not refer to the class variable (or attribute) - it is an instance attribute.